# Substring a word from string with charindex in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query to extract a word from a string. For example, I want to get the word `Final` from the sentence: `this is the final exam`.

I want only to get the word 'final' using charindex to determine the start and end of the substring function.

Comment: Please check here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp

Comment: thanks for sharing this with me. I know this would do the work, but I want to use charindex with it ti determine the start and the end points.

Comment: Ok, try this `SELECT PATINDEX('%final%', 'this is the final exam');` for more details
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_patindex.asp

Comment: great! this really good, but I dont want to specify the word 'final'. I want to get the word that start with the letters 'Fi' and end with the letter 'al'. this is what I am looking for. Thanks again

Comment: Do you really expect `Final` with an upper case `F`, from `final`?

Comment: it is not case sensitive.

Comment: @D.Jhon . . . Your comment totally changes your question.  I would suggest that you delete this question.  Ask another question and be quite clear on what you are looking for.  Sample data and desired results -- more than one example -- would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for. Please have a look at this:

```
Declare @start INT;
Declare @end int;

set @start=CHARINDEX('Fi','this is the final exam');
set @end =CHARINDEX('al','this is the final exam');
if(@start >0 and @end>0)
Begin
SELECT
       SUBSTRING('this is the final exam', 
                  @start, 
                  5)
END
```